# Mock not being called in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Please help me understand Jest mocks.

I've put some dummy functions in a file:

```js
// actions.js
export function f1() {
  return 1
}

export function calls_f1() {
  f1()
}
```

And then in my test file I'm trying to understand how to check that a function calls another function:

```js
import * as actions from './actions.js'

describe("MOCKS", () => {
  actions.f1 = jest.fn();
  actions.calls_f1();
  expect(actions.f1).toBeCalled();
});
```

But the test is failing saying the mock function wasn't called. I've also tried swapping the 2nd and 3rd lines of the test, to no avail.

My jest config is all good, I've actually been doing a bunch of other testing (in this same file) that works.

What am I missing here?

---

Note: The actual implementation of this (that I'm simplifying greatly here) involves an `actions` file that includes a public `export function fetchStations()` that calls a private (or, rather, not exported) `export function _downloadStations()`. I'm trying to test that `_downloadStations()` is called.

I'm using `import * as actions` only for convenience, so I can write that line and then use whatever functions that file exports under `actions.whatever()` (instead of having to add functions to the import statement when I decide to use them). If `import * as actions` has some effect I'm not noticing (as implied by brian below) then I certainly don't have to use it and can use `import {thisAction, thatAction} from './actions'` of course.

Comment: ah, if `_downloadStations` is not exported then there is no way to wrap it in a spy to test that it has been called since it is just an internal implementation detail of the module and not visible outside the module.  In that case you are limited to testing for the effects that calling `_downloadStations` causes...I added an update to my answer below to reflect that information.

Comment: I've edit this to make it `export function _downloadStations`. I can make this change to make testing possible (or use rewire or something to make it possible without making the method public). Still not doing any cyclic importing in the source file.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```js
import * as actions from './actions.js'
```

binds the module exports from `actions.js` to `actions`...

...so setting `actions.f1` to a mock function replaces the *module export* for `f1`...

...but this doesn't affect `calls_f1` since it calls `f1` directly.

---

If `calls_f1` is changed to call the *module export* for `f1` then it will call the mock function.

---

There are two ways to make that happen.

One way is to move `f1` into its own module.

The other way is to note that ES6 modules ["support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_cyclic-dependencies) (a major design goal of ES6 modules) so a module can import its own exports:

actions.js

```js
import * as actions from './actions';  // <= import the module...

export function f1() {
  return 1
}

export function calls_f1() {
  actions.f1()  // <= ...and use it to call f1
}
```

actions.test.js

```js
import * as actions from './actions.js'

describe('actions', () => {
  it('calls_f1 should call f1', () => {
    actions.f1 = jest.fn();
    actions.calls_f1();
    expect(actions.f1).toBeCalled();  // Success!
  })
})
```

---

**Update**

OP updated the question to indicate that the function in question is not exported from the module.

In that case it is just an internal implementation detail of the module and cannot be spied on directly.

Testing it would involve testing for the effects that it causes, and not directly spying on it to see if it was called.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I did (of course) get this exact code to work. How can I do this without including the cyclic import in my `actions` file? It seems like that extra import is there just to make the tests work. Maybe it's "putting f1 in its own module" as you said, but I'm not exactly sure what that means.

Comment: There just needs to be a level of indirection...calling `f1` as a property of an object.  That lets you replace the property of the object with the mock.  If `f1` is called directly there is no way to override that.  Importing a module into itself works, putting both functions in a wrapping object works, moving `f1` to a different module works, whichever makes the most sense to you. @JonathanTuzman

Comment: "putting f1 in it's own module" just means creating another file (like `f1.js`, for example) that contains `f1`, and then importing it into `actions.js` so `calls_f1` calls it as a property of the module it is defined in...that gives you the indirection needed to replace it with something different during your tests.  @JonathanTuzman